# Symmetric fat-tailed distributions where $\mathbb{E} e^X < \infty$

Tags: distributions

What "fat-tailed distributions" $p(x)$, symmetric about zero, have the property
$$\newcommand{\e}{\mathbb{E}}\newcommand{\rd}{\mathrm{d}}
\e e^X = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^x p(x) \rd x < \infty \> ?
$$

**Context**

I'm attempting to price financial options for $X$ without using the Black–Scholes formula. It is usually easier to work with the log-price $Y = \log(X)$ and often it is assumed that $Y$ is normally distributed.

Empirical observations (eg, the "volatility smile") suggest that $Y$ isn't normal; the normal distribution decreases too rapidly away from 0. Thus, we need a fat-tailed distribution.

The value of a call option increases exponentially as $Y$ increases linearly. Therefore, $p(x)$ must decline fast enough that $\e e^X < \infty$. In other words, the distribution must decline slower than the normal distribution, but still fast enough that $\e e^X$ converges.

I tried the Cauchy and Student's $t$ distributions, but $\e e^X$ diverges for both, regardless of parameters.

I also realize I can create arbitrary distributions meeting my conditions (though I'm not exactly sure how), but I'm looking for a well-known (parametrized family of) distribution.

Even more details (for the masochist): 
https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-imp-vol.m

Comment: It is better to use $\LaTeX$ instead of Mathematica syntax for maths, the first is interpreted here.

Comment: Setting $p(x) = 0$ for $x > M$ is definitely *not* fat-tailed by any standard definition.

Comment: @barrycarter, I have tried to fully rewrite and reformat your question without altering the content. To do so, I've introduced the variable $Y$. But, that more clearly brings out a bit of ambiguity in the original question regarding whether you are interested in the stated property for $X$ itself or for $Y$. I actually believe it is for $Y$, but I've strived hard to make the question a bit more reader-friendly without altering the content. You're welcome to roll back the revision. In any event, I **strongly** recommend you *edit* it to clarify whether the main object of interest is $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: @cardinal - setting $p(x)=0$ for $x>M$ is not unrealistic for large enough $M$.  I would say this is the only truly realistic way to model anything, because infinity doesn't exist in the real world.  Its just hard to say exactly what that $M$ is, and by taking the limit as $M\to\infty$ is a useful approximation which opens up analytic methods.  But one cannot claim for it to be "exact" - even if no mathematical approximations have been made.

Comment: @probabilityislogic, your point is well taken. However, my intent was to address terminology in order to (hopefully) reduce confusion and (possible) misinterpretation. A density function supported on a compact set is pretty much the antithesis of "fat-tailed".

Comment: @cardinal - I would disagree here.  For if I put a mass $p_M$ at $x=M$ and then distribute the rest according to a pdf defined on $0<x<M$ I have arbitrarily large probability mass in the tail of the distribution, and hence "fat tails".  A less pathological example is a Cauchy distribution, restricted to $|x|<M$.  This density still has "fat tails" relative to densities defined on $|x|<M$ - just that there is some densities with fatter tails defined on a larger support

Comment: @probabilityislogic: [Heavy tailed distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution). Precision is used in mathematical terminology so that everyone can agree on what's being discussed. Many times the terms used are meant to be evocative of some intuition, but also end up being a little at odds with colloquial meanings.

Comment: @cardinal Thanks for editing! I cleaned it up further and removed my erroneous comment re P(x)=0 for x>M being fat-tailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variance gamma process is a useful way to go.  It is an extension of the standard brownian motion process, $Z(t)$

$$Y(t;\mu,\sigma,\nu)=\mu \Gamma(t;1,\nu) + \sigma Z(\Gamma[t;1,\nu])$$

Where $\Gamma(t;1,\nu)$ is a gamma process, with independent gamma distributed increments.  So $\Gamma(t+s;1,\nu)-\Gamma(t;1,\nu)$ has a gamma distribution with mean $s$ and variance $s\nu$.  (you could replace the $1$ by another parameter $\mu$ if desired, to have mean $s\mu$, as is done [here](http://www.math.nyu.edu/research/carrp/papers/pdf/VGEFRpub.pdf)).  The intuition is that "time" is measured in some sort of trading volume rather than calendar time.  So it incorporates a sense of the market "getting hot" and "getting cold".

This process has the "fat tail" property that you seek, and is commonly used as an option pricing model.  It can be used by averaging the Black–Scholes option price with respect to gamma distribution for the time.

The increments of this distribution $Y(t)-Y(s)$ follow a Laplace distribution.

More generally one speaks of what are called Levy process, which have characteristic function $\varphi_{y}(\theta)=E[\exp(i\theta Y_{t})]$:

$$\varphi_{t}(\theta)=\exp\left(it\mu\theta - \frac{t}{2}\sigma^{2}\theta^{2}+t\int_{|x|<\epsilon}[e^{i\theta x}-1-i\theta x]d\Pi(x)+t\int_{|x|>\epsilon}[e^{i\theta x}-1]d\Pi(x)\right)$$

Where $d\Pi(x)$ is called the Levy measure, and governs discontinuities in the process (or the "jumps").  The measure must satisfy:

$$\int_{|x|<\epsilon}x^{2}d\Pi(x)<\infty$$
$$\int_{|x|>\epsilon}d\Pi(x)<\infty$$

Thus it can have a singularity at zero as long it is not "too big".  Can show for the variance gamma process the Levy measure is given by:

$$d\Pi(x)=\frac{dx}{\nu|x|}\exp(-\frac{1}{\nu}|x|)$$

**UPDATE**

In regards to Cardinal's well directed comments (I have a tendency to "wander-off" when I'm doing some sort of maths) you can see that the only criterion for your "fat tailed" distribution to satisfy your criterion is that the moment generating function $m_{X}(t)=E[\exp(tX)]$ exists when evaluated at $t=1$.  Equivalently we require the characteristic function to exist when evaluated at $\theta=-i$.  Because the Levy-process is defined by its CF then it is always finite when the two integral equations above are satisfied.  The expectation is given by the above formula

Comment: This is a good start to an answer to the OP's question, I think. The notation should be clarified somewhat, particularly the meaning of $\Gamma[t;\,1,v]$, and the OP's specific queries regarding symmetry (for what values of the parameters?) and the finiteness of $\mathbb{E} e^Y$ should be addressed. There are several freely available references on using these models to price options, so providing those in the answer as well would go along way to wrapping up all loose ends.

Comment: @probabilityislogic, sorry to pester. That's not my intent. The argument to the ch.f. is treated as a real number and so, lacking more info, your update seems a bit heuristic. Indeed, in the complex plane, the ch.f. Is defined for every point on the imaginary axis only. The mgf, when it exists, is defined on an interval of the *real axis* around the origin. So, for an argument like yours to work, you'd need to know something more than just the ch.f. Do you mind providing the reference you've used for the development so far?

Comment: @cardinal - you are right in my argument being a bit heuristic.  My references are the article linked in, and my course notes from university - textbook for the course was *Options, Futures and Other Derivatives (6th Edition)* by John C Hull.  I can make it more precise by noting that the expected value of $X^{R}$ is equal to the $R$th derivative of the CF evaluated at $0$ divided by $i^{R}$.  Can show that for VG process, the CF is infinitely differentiable at zero - hence all moments exist, hence MGF exist, hence my quick way should give same answer.

Comment: (cont'd) you can also show more directly by first conditioning on the gamma process $E[\exp(X)|\Gamma]$ which is just a log-normal expectation.  Then you can integrate this conditional expectation w.r.t a gamma distribution, and all is good

Comment: @probabilityislogic, that's starting to sound closer along with the verification of some necessary continuity assumptions. I still think you may only get an mgf for certain values of the parameters, though. Hull is a pretty good reference for intuition. His math tends to be very hand-wavy, though, if I recall. (I don't know the book well. It must be in its 20th edition or so, by now.)

Comment: @probabilityislogic Thanks! The variance gamma distributions might do exactly what I want. I saw the Levy distribution on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution but ignored it, since it was one-tailed. I'm guessing it can be adjusted to be symmetric around 0?

Comment: @barry - it isn't one tailed - conditional on the gamma process, it is just plain old ordinary brownian motion (with drift and volatility).  Its just that instead of using calendar time, it uses a stochastic process to measure time - usually called "market time".  You can also think of a brownian motion with "jumps"

Answer (score 3):

The definition of fat-tail in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_tail) is that

$$p(x)\sim x^{-(\alpha+1)}$$

as $x\to\infty$ for some $\alpha>0$. Now

$$\frac{e^x}{x^{\alpha+1}}\to\infty,$$

as $x\to\infty$, so the $Ee^X$ cannot exist for such type of distributions. So you need to precise what do you have in mind by saying fat-tailed.

Comment: (+1) It might be worth noting *why* this is the case, as it may not be clear to all readers. For example, it follows from Markov's inequality.

Comment: @cardinal, I think more pedestrian reason that the integrand function must at least converge to zero at infinity if we integrate over all line is sufficient. That is why I did not add any notes.

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed over your answer a bit too fast. I tend to think of heavy-tailed distributions in terms of upper-tail probabilities, which is where my remark originated from. For me, thinking about upper tails avoids having to make distinctions regarding whether a density exists or not.